# How to show that $\dim(Im f)=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $g: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ be a linear tranformation, such that $g(v)=0 \space \forall \space v \in \mathbb{R^3}$. Let $f: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$, such that $f\neq g$ and $f \circ f=g$. Show that $\dim(Im \space f)=1$.

My thought was, as $g(v)=0 \space \forall \space v \in \mathbb{R^3}$, one have that $\dim(Im \space g)=0$. So $\dim(Im \space f \circ f)=0$ also. Because $g:\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$, then $g$ is not bijective as well $f \circ f$.

But I don't kown what to say about $f$. How can I show that $\dim(Im \space f)=1$? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $g$ is the zero transformation and since $f^2=0$ then 
$$\operatorname{Im}(f)\subset\ker f$$
hence
$$\dim(\operatorname{Im}(f))\le\dim(\ker f)$$
and by the rank-nullity theorem we have
$$\dim(\operatorname{Im}(f))+\dim(\ker f)=3$$
hence $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(f))=0$ or $1$. The first value isn't possible since $f\ne0$. Conclude.

Comment: Why $Im(f)$ is a subset of $ker(f)$? Can you explain me? Thanks.

Comment: If $y\in\operatorname{Im}(f)$ then $y=f(x)$ and then 
$$f(y)=f(f(x))=f^2(x)=0$$
hence $y\in \ker (f)$. @João

Comment: Ohhh,I get it! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.@João

Answer (score 1):

We have $3 = \dim Im f + \dim \ker f$.  Since $f^2 = g$, we have $Im f \subseteq \ker f$

If $\dim \ker f = 3$, then $\dim Im f = 0$, impossible. So we're left with $\dim \ker f = 2$, in which case $\dim Im f = 1$.